# PhoneGap - How to make a copy of image and save in application folder?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

In my app the user can choose one image from gallery, this image will be used in user account and can't be accessible by gallery, so I need sabe a copy of this image into `cordova.file.dataDirectory` but I don't know how to get local file URI to make copy and save.

How to copy image file from local device to `cordova.file.dataDirectory`?

My app have a screen where user can give title and choose image using a input file.

I'm using [cordova plugin file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching I found solution in old documentation of PhoneGap (recent docs no have this information). To copy files just use [copyTo method](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html).

```
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(entry){
        var parent = document.getElementById('parent').value;
        parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry({fullPath: parent});

        // copy the file to a new directory and rename it
        entry.copyTo(parentEntry, "file.copy", function(entry){
            console.log("New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error.code);
        });

    }, null);
```